# JavaCC lookahead acting different, not choosing the correct method to parse

Tags: java, parsing, javacc, regex-lookarounds

I am new to JavaCC, and have read multiple lookahead tutorials. However when testing lookahead on a simple grammar file have left me puzzled. In this grammar file I just made two parsing rules, 1->double, 2->integers.

The program is supposed to choose on of them, if the input suits the context.

```
options
{
  STATIC =false;
  debug_parser = true;
  debug_lookahead = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(testin)
public class testin
{
    public void parse() throws ParseException
    {
        testin b = new testin(System.in);
        b.go();
    }
}
PARSER_END(testin)

TOKEN:
{
//testing lookahead
<NUMBER : (["0"-"9"])+>|
<DOT : ".">
}


void go()
:
{}
{

LOOKAHEAD(2) doub() | number()
}

void doub()
:
{
Token bool;
}
{
bool = <NUMBER><DOT><NUMBER>
{
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(bool.image));
}
} 

void number()
:
{
Token mo;
}
{
mo = <NUMBER>
{
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(mo.image));
}
}
```

After testing with this code when typing with decimals the input, it works, but when typing with an integer it doesn't and it doesn't output anything. Here is the debug output:

```
Call:   go
Call:   doub(LOOKING AHEAD...)
75
   Visited token: <<NUMBER>: "75" at line 1 column 1>; Expected token:<<NUMBER>>
```

Comment: After 75 you hit return. This should cause a TokenManagerError to be thrown.  Are you sure your program didn't throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the whitespace characters:

```
SKIP : {
    < " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" >
}
```

Also, try to specify where the `<EOF>` is expected:

```
void go()
:
{}
{
(LOOKAHEAD(2) doub() | number())
<EOF>
}
```

Comment: Umm, doesn't work, it seems like the parser just enters the doub() method right away.

Comment: @Pun3rs yes, but it will backtrack if necessary.

Comment: @Pun3rs Also, I believe that you should distinguish between integers and doubles at the lexical level; i.e. define two tokens,

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I intentionally did this to learn the Lookahead system. So in future cases I can implement the Lookahead system.